# Allow some HTML elements in markdown lint rule MD033 in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

When authoring Markdown in Visual Studio Code with the [markdownlint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidAnson.vscode-markdownlint) extension installed, I am seeing lint message `MD033/no-inline-html: Inline HTML`.

[image]

How can I configure the linter not to warn me about a few specific HTML elements?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create a `.markdownlint.json` file in the same folder as your markdown file:

```
{
  "MD033": {
    "allowed_elements": [
      "nobr",
      "sup"
    ]
  }
}
```

To configure other rules, see the `Parameters:` listed under each rule [here](https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint/blob/main/doc/Rules.md#md033).

Answer (score 12):

Adding to [Wallace Kelly's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72368494/5125223), you can create a `.vscode/settings.json` file and paste this to make this config project level:

```json
{
  "markdownlint.config": {
    "MD033": {
      "allowed_elements": ["nobr", "sup", "a"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to configure it for all projects and in general way with VS code, add to `seetings.json` file:

```json
  "markdownlint.config": {
    "MD033": {
      "allowed_elements": ["nobr", "sup", "a"]
    }
  },
```

Comment: When you say, "for all projects"... in what folder do you place this file?